# Where to find rules for jshint in Atom text editor for angularJS (1.xx) development?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, atom-editor, jshint, linter

I'm new to LINTER plugins on Atom text editor. I used LINTER(a plugin for Atom) and ESLINT(a plugin for Atom) to develop react native apps few month ago. So, I used some rules to configure Atom called 'rallycoding' using npm as follows.

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-config-rallycoding
```

Then I created `.eslintrc` file as below:

```
{
"extends": "rallycoding"
}
```

Now I want to do the same thing for Atom to develop AngularJS (1.x) apps. So I installed following plugins for Atom:

1. jshint
2. linter

But I don't know how to set rules appropriate to Angular. I also want to know what append with "rallycoding" in the previous case.

Answer (score -1):

you can find a lot of config with a quick look to [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/)

just look for eslint-config and you will find a lot of config for your scenario, here are the one you looking for

[esling-config-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-angular)